# UI5 OData for a flat structure

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-gateway

In my company we started using UI5 and I've already done 2 simple reports.
When I created the OData for the report I imported it from a function that exported a table type.

Now I've created a Function that imports 2 RANGES and exports a flat structure and I have no idea how to create the OData for it.

I've looked up in the internet and here in stack overflow and couldn't find any resource regarding this.

How do I make the OData so the UI5 developer can consume the data in the flat structure.

I'm sorry if its too general, if it is let me know and I will try to add more info.

Thank you.

EDIT: Do I need to just export the fields instead exporting the structure?
Its a 4 fields structure right now.

Comment: Usually when you have an entity you have a method to get a single entity (strucuture) and another method to get an entity set (table).

Comment: `Now I've created a Function that imports 2 RANGES` give FM exact input and output params, full structures